# Getting a string to display whilst using getpass() in python

Tags: python, getpasswd

I'm using python and getpass() to get credentials from the terminal window. Whilst not displaying the credentials, it would be nice to display something in real-time. e.g * or # etc.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990998/how-to-have-password-echoed-as-asterisks