# Password Input for Python

Tags: python, password-protection, python-3.5

Is there any way of make python have a password input???

instead of:

```
Whats your password?
password     <--- this is a user input
```

I need:

```
Whats your password?
********     <--- this is a user input
```

Is that possible in python???

Comment: did you checkout the getpass library

Answer (score 5):

You can hide the input by using [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html):

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass("Whats your password?")
```

Comment: Is there a way of making it display asterisks???

Comment: No, though I believe the `curses` library can do that. However, displaying asterisks would be considered a vulnerability by some (least because it displays the number of characters the user has input).

Comment: you can also use tkinter, which definitely has a way to show other characters but it is a gui interface. Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990998/how-to-have-password-echoed-as-asterisks

Comment: How would I do that @JayT.

Comment: tkinter is a library for python that you can import and use, but as I already mentioned it is used to develop gui and I don't think can be used for command line.