# How do I convert a password into asterisks while it is being entered?

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to convert characters as they are being entered by the user to asterisks, like it can be seen on many websites?

For example, if an email user was asked to sign in to their account, while typing in their password, it wouldn't appear as characters but rather as `*` after each individual stroke without any time lag.

If the actual password was `KermitTheFrog`, it would appear as `*************` when typed in.

I am not asking about how to disable echoing characters to the screen, which is what Python's `getpass.getpass()` module does. I specifically want the feature where asterisks appear in response to key presses, which `getpass` doesn't do.

Comment: This is pretty vague, to me - what is your source of input? A web page? Terminal? A tkinter text area? Yes to all, but it's different for each

Comment: I was actually doing this for a school project and i'm a very basic programmer.... but i'll try to use the tkinter text area so if u could help with that it'd be great

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want a solution that works on Windows/macOS/Linux and on Python 2 & 3, you can install the `pwinput` module (formerly called stdiomask):

```
pip install pwinput
```

Unlike `getpass.getpass()` (which is in the Python Standard Library), the `pwinput` module can display *** mask characters as you type. It is also cross-platform, while `getpass` is Linux and macOS only.

Example usage:

```
>>> pwinput.pwinput()
Password: *********
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(mask='X') # Change the mask character.
Password: XXXXXXXXX
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(prompt='PW: ', mask='*') # Change the prompt.
PW: *********
'swordfish'
>>> pwinput.pwinput(mask='') # Don't display anything.
Password:
'swordfish'
```

Unfortunately this module, like Python's built-in `getpass` module, doesn't work in IDLE or Jupyter Notebook.

More details at https://pypi.org/project/pwinput/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "`getpass` is Linux and macOS only".  Python's documentation describes `getpass` as "Portable password input".  While it might not reliably disable echoing on all platforms, it should always be available, falling back to reading from stdin if necessary.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was thinking of another module other than `getpass`. The `getpass` module doesn't and has never displayed the asterisks.

Answer (score 43):

There is [`getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass), a function which *hides* the user input.

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass()
print(password)
```

Comment: yes but do you know something that could display (*) instead of nothing while typing the password?

Comment: This hides the password entirely. It does not display asterisks (*).

Comment: Not true today, in Python 3.7, using a Jupyter lab cell. I get bullet points (or are those very small asterisks?)!

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Tkinter:

```
# For Python 2:
from Tkinter import Entry, Tk
# For Python 3
from tkinter import Entry, Tk

master = Tk()

Password = Entry(master, bd=5, width=20, show="*")
Password.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

[image: Password entry with tkinter]

In the shell, this is not possible. You can however write a function to store the entered text and report only a string of *'s when called.
[Kinda like this](http://pythonfiddle.com/censor-replace-with-asterisks/), which I did not write. I just Googled it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
# if getch module is available, then we implement our own getpass() with asterisks,
# otherwise we just use the plain boring getpass.getpass()
try:
    import getch
    def getpass(prompt):
        """Replacement for getpass.getpass() which prints asterisks for each character typed"""
        print(prompt, end='', flush=True)
        buf = ''
        while True:
            ch = getch.getch()
            if ch == '\n':
                print('')
                break
            else:
                buf += ch
                print('*', end='', flush=True)
        return buf
except ImportError:
    from getpass import getpass
```

Comment: May want to handle backspaces and Ctrl + U

Answer (score 3):

first install the library:

```
pip install stdiomask
```

note that you install std io mask not studiomask...

And then the code is:

```
password = stdiomask.getpass() # It will ask to enter password and display * on the screen

print(password)
```

This is the output:

```
Password: *****
google
```

Comment: Minor note: the stdiomask module is now called pwinput. See the other answer in this question for more info.

Answer (score 2):

while using `getpass` in python, nothing is indicated to show a password input.

this can be resolved by this simple solution:

just copy the `‘getpass_ak.py’` module provided in the link to python’s Lib folder.

https://starrernet.wixsite.com/analytix/python-coder

***use the following code:***

```
import getpass_ak

a = (getpass_ak.getpass('password: '))
```

this will add * to your password inputs.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who would actually want to have asterisks appear, here's an improvement on [Tigran Aivazian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636454/11498682). This version imports the built-in `msvcrt.getch`, adds cases for different line endings when hitting 'Enter/Return', and includes logic to support Backspace, as well as Ctrl+C (KeyboardInterrupt):

```py
try:
    from msvcrt import getch
    def getpass(prompt):
        """Replacement for getpass.getpass() which prints asterisks for each character typed"""
        print(prompt, end='', flush=True)
        buf = b''
        while True:
            ch = getch()
            if ch in {b'\n', b'\r', b'\r\n'}:
                print('')
                break
            elif ch == b'\x08': # Backspace
                buf = buf[:-1]
                print(f'\r{(len(prompt)+len(buf)+1)*" "}\r{prompt}{"*" * len(buf)}', end='', flush=True)
            elif ch == b'\x03': # Ctrl+C
                raise KeyboardInterrupt
            else:
                buf += ch
                print('*', end='', flush=True)
        return buf.decode(encoding='utf-8')
except ImportError:
    from getpass import getpass
```

Please feel free to suggest any other changes, or ways to improve this; I hacked the changes together pretty quickly, especially with the Backspace logic.

Answer (score 1):

I have combined the answers of *@Tigran Aivazian* and *@Ahndwoo* into fully working solution:

- ! additional code for the backspace `{b'\x08', b'\x7f'}: # Backspace` is added
- for the `Ctrl+C` combination the silent return is used. The `raise KeyboardInterrupt` is commented now, but can be uncommented for raise the error.

```
# if getch module is available, then we implement our own getpass() with asterisks,
# otherwise we just use the plain boring getpass.getpass()
try:
    from getch import getch
    def getpass(prompt):
        """Replacement for getpass.getpass() which prints asterisks for each character typed"""
        print(prompt, end='', flush=True)
        buf = b''
        while True:
            ch = getch().encode()
            if ch in {b'\n', b'\r', b'\r\n'}:
                print('')
                break
            elif ch == b'\x03': # Ctrl+C
                # raise KeyboardInterrupt
                return ''
            elif ch in {b'\x08', b'\x7f'}: # Backspace
                buf = buf[:-1]
                print(f'\r{(len(prompt)+len(buf)+1)*" "}\r{prompt}{"*" * len(buf)}', end='', flush=True)
            else:
                buf += ch
                print('*', end='', flush=True)

        return buf.decode(encoding='utf-8')
except ImportError:
    from getpass import getpass

password = getpass('Enter password: ')
print(password)
```

Comment: Very nice start, as a password helper written in python.

Evolution is almost identical to something I wrote in shell.
  https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#askpass_stars

Answer (score 1):

My own suggestion is --  **DO NOT DO IT!**

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a password helper if you want 'stars'

Instead do something like the following pseudo-code... If the TTY_ASSPASS environment variable is set -- call that password helper. There are a number available, including "systemd-ask-password" If there is a TTY - fall back to read no echo (getpass.getpass()) If there is no TTY, - fall back just read STDIN with rstrip()

This not only lets the user select a password input program (via an environment variable (or some other confuguration), but also lets them substitute for other sources of passwords, like GUI input, or collecting password from a pre-opened keyring password daemon, or elsewhere

Don't restrict or otherwise limit where passwords come from!

For notes on password helpers see.. https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/crypto/passwd_input.txt

For a shell script password helper https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#askpass_stars

Looks like Andrei Krivoshei answer has already made a start on that, resulting in something very similar, but still in its infancy.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) function.

> Prompt the user for a password without echoing. The user is prompted
>   using the string prompt, which defaults to 'Password: '. On Unix, the
>   prompt is written to the file-like object stream. stream defaults to
>   the controlling terminal (/dev/tty) or if that is unavailable to
>   sys.stderr (this argument is ignored on Windows).

Note: This module mimics unix password prompts and does not show asterisks.

Usage:

```
import getpass
getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: Men, you got beat by a few seconds, did ya? ;)