# Is it possible to hide the getpass() warning?

Tags: python, hide, getpass

Is it possible to hide the message that gets displayed if getpass() cannot hide the message?

```
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
```

Is it possible to replace this message with something else more user friendly? If it is, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use getpass() to hide a users password as it is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47167139/how-to-use-getpass-to-hide-a-users-password-as-it-is-entered)

Comment: @BlueRobin , I'm looking for how to hide the warning (if it's possible) and print something more user-friendly.

Comment: Does the answer on the question, answer that though?

Comment: no... sorry. I'm looking for a way to hide the warning. Even if the thing running the code cannot stop echoing, I want it to print something more user friendly (if it's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this message isn't intended to be customizable. Here's a workaround.

Behind the scenes, `getpass.getpass` is the following function when echo can't be disabled.

```py
def fallback_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None):
    warnings.warn("Can not control echo on the terminal.", GetPassWarning,
                  stacklevel=2)
    if not stream:
        stream = sys.stderr
    print("Warning: Password input may be echoed.", file=stream)
    return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
```

If you want to customize the message, you could just write your own function that calls `getpass._raw_input`. For example,

```py
import sys
import getpass

def custom_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None):
    if not stream:
        stream = sys.stderr
    print("This is a custom message to the user.", file=stream)
    return getpass._raw_input(prompt, stream)
```

You can then call your `custom_getpass` function directly, or you can replace `getpass.getpass` with your custom function.

```py
getpass.getpass = custom_getpass

# This prints "This is a custom message to the user." before getting the
# password.
getpass.getpass()
```

Note that the approach above will *always* print the custom warning and will always echo the password to the user. If you only want to use the custom function when the fallback `getpass` is being used, you could do that by simply checking which function `getpass` is using for `getpass.getpass`. For example

```py
if getpass.getpass == getpass.fallback_getpass:
    getpass.getpass = custom_getpass

# If echo could not be disabled, then this prints "This is a custom
# message to the user." before getting the password.
getpass.getpass()
```

Beware this could break without notice in future versions of Python since the workaround relies on the module's "private" functions.