# python getpass password input with asterisks

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to  get asterisks during inputting password using getpass module in python?

actual Results:

```
import getpass                                                                       

p=getpass.getpass("Enter the Password:")

Enter the Password:

print (p)

Output: password
```

Expecting results:

```
import getpass                                                                       

p=getpass.getpass("Enter the Password:")

Enter the Password:********

print (p)

Output: password
```

Python Version: 2.7

Comment: `getpass` doesn't have that functionality. You don't get stars, you just get an un-echoed password, if the terminal can do that. FWIW, printing stars is less secure, because it lets an onlooker know how long the password is.

Comment: It does have the functionality but does so only when echo free input is unavailable and when it does, it prints a warning message to stream. [source](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html)

Comment: This question was answered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078/how-do-i-convert-a-password-into-asterisks-while-it-is-being-entered/52636454#52636454

Comment: @TigranAivazian The accepted answer of the linked question hides the input completely, rather than display stars.

Comment: You can find answer for this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078/how-do-i-convert-a-password-into-asterisks-while-it-is-being-entered/35805111

Comment: Concealing password length from shoulder-surfers is a very minor security benefit, while not acknowledging input with anything is a large usability cost.