# How do I hide input WITHOUT getpass (it doesn't work)?

Tags: python, python-idle, getpass

I've been trying to make a simple sign-up/in program and I wanted to hide the password, so I took to the internet.

I tried out this thing called getpass, but it didn't work. It just told me it couldn't change the echo in IDLE's shell.(I use IDLE Python 3.6 on Windows 10 btw)

So I was wondering if there's a way to hide the input without getpass, or to encrypt it some other way?

Here's the code:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, un, pw):
        self.un = un
        self.pw = pw

accounts = []

#account signing up

def signup():
    usernm = input("Make a username >>> ")
    passwd = input("Make a password >>> ")
    accounts.append(Account(usernm, passwd))

def signin():
    inun = input("Username? >>> ")
    inpw = input("Password >>> ")
    for account in accounts:
        if account.un == inun:
            if account.pw == inpw:
                print("Signed in!")



option = input("Sign [i]n or sign [u]p? >>> ").lower()
if option == "i":
    signin()
if option == "u":
    signup()
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You mean you want entered passwords to be stars as they're typed?

Comment: Yes, IDLE is not intended for use in the "real world" it's for dev purposes only, so it won't support all kinds of things that you would normally see in a traditional command line shell. If you want to test what it would look like, open cmd or terminal and do `python my_script.py` to see what it would look like in a "real" terminal.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well, that could be one way. But mainly want to hide it completely, as stars would give away the number of characters

Comment: @Ares Well using the getpass command in the terminal worked. However the whole program didn't. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Going back to your idea, I could replace with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The `getpass` completely  works for me, so i would assume that you didnt used the correct syntax

```
import getpass
 
p = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter Your password: ')
```

But if you are saying `getpass` didnt work because you cannot see any change in cursor, then you are wrong. `getpass` just shows an un-echoed password (*means it wont send the key strokes the the terminal*).

The Python IDLE or console meant for developing propose, not to use in program made for users. So I would recommend you to use some sort of GUI like Tkinter to fulfill you propose.

But if you want the cursor to move, there are 2 solution below:

- For Python IDLE, use this [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64526061/16187613)
- For Tkinter, you can use `Entry` widget, try `Entry(root, show="*")`, this would show "*" for every key you enter.