# Mask terminal output with Asterisk, but still be able to copy and paste the original value

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I have been searching for quite some time, trying to find how to mask terminal OUTPUT.

Example:

```
print(password)
terminal:
********
```

But still be able to copy and paste the password value.

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35805111/4045754

Comment: Not really. You see getPass masks the input value. What i want is to mask the output value while still being able to copy and paste it somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an answer to this. I have asked around :(

I worked around this problem. The goal was to be able to put the password in the clipboard. So I used [Pyperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pyperclip/info) to do it :)

Comment: The reason it can't be done as described is because the system that handles selecting text in a terminal and copying it has no way to know about the "hidden" characters; it's operating completely independently of your program.