# Python: hiding input characters with Stars

Tags: python, data-hiding

I am requesting user input. I am asking for username then password.
EG

```py
username = input('Please enter a Username:\n')
password = input('Please enter a Password:\n')
```

When run this will of course appear like this:

```
Please enter a Username:
Iain
Please enter a Password:
Iain
```

What I want is this:

```
Please enter a Username:
Iain
Please enter a Password:
****
```

Comment: I suggested `getpass` but that hides input, not replace it with stars.

Comment: You will like to [rewrite the last line(s) of the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console) and then print the stars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a password into asterisks while it is being entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078/how-do-i-convert-a-password-into-asterisks-while-it-is-being-entered) Please search to see if your question has already been asked and answered before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called *pwinput*.

You can install it using pip: `pip3 install pwinput`.

And use it as follows:

```
import pwinput
password = pwinput.pwinput()
```

This would open a prompt like this:

```
Password: ****
```

If you want to remove the text 'Password:', you can do:

```
password = pwinput.pwinput(prompt='')
```