# Python - How to convert a password into asterisks while it is being entered by the user?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way in Python to convert characters as they are being entered by the user to asterisks, like it can be seen on many websites?

For example, if an user sets his password as " pass@123" then while entering it should be like

```
Password : ********
```

I installed pwinput module but I'm unable to import it. While importing it is showing

```
import pwinput
```

"pwinput" is not accessed Pylance

Import "pwinput" could not be resolved Pylance ([reportMissingImports](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportMissingImports))

This is the code where I'm prompting password from the user :

```
def registration():
    Fname = input("Enter first name: ")
    Lname = input("Enter last name: ")
    while(True):
        gender = input("Enter your gender: ")
        if(gender not in "MmFf"):
            print("THE GENDER YOU HAVE ENTERED IS INCORRECT TRY AGAIN ")
        else:
            break
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    phoneno = int(input("Enter your phone number: "))
    city = input("Enter your city: ")
    email = input("Enter your email id: ")
    while True:
        passwd = input("Enter your password: ")
        repasswd = input("Re-enter your password: ")
        if passwd!=repasswd:
            print("Password doesn't match. Try again!")
        else:
            break
    Q = "insert into registration values ('"+Fname +"','"+Lname+"','"+gender+"',"+str(phoneno)+","+str(age)+",'"+email+"','"+passwd+"','"+city+"');"
    mycursor.execute(Q)
    mydb.commit()
    print("Registration done successfully!")
```

What am I missing here? And what is the correct solution for it?

Comment: What code are you using to prompt the user for a password? Can you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Dash I have added the code snippet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a password into asterisks while it is being entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805078/how-do-i-convert-a-password-into-asterisks-while-it-is-being-entered)

Comment: The simplest is probably using [pwinput](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324038/13525512)

Comment: @Tranbi I have installed pwinput but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in my comment, using `pwinput` will require the least change to your code. After installing `pwinput` with `pip install pwinput` import it in your code and replace the corresponding occurences of `input`:

```
from pwinput import pwinput

def registration():
    Fname = input("Enter first name: ")
    Lname = input("Enter last name: ")
    while(True):
        gender = input("Enter your gender: ")
        if(gender not in "MmFf"):
            print("THE GENDER YOU HAVE ENTERED IS INCORRECT TRY AGAIN ")
        else:
            break
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    phoneno = int(input("Enter your phone number: "))
    city = input("Enter your city: ")
    email = input("Enter your email id: ")
    while True:
        passwd = pwinput("Enter your password: ")
        repasswd = pwinput("Re-enter your password: ")
        if passwd!=repasswd:
            print("Password doesn't match. Try again!")
        else:
            break
    Q = "insert into registration values ('"+Fname +"','"+Lname+"','"+gender+"',"+str(phoneno)+","+str(age)+",'"+email+"','"+passwd+"','"+city+"');"
    #mycursor.execute(Q)
    #mydb.commit()
    print("Registration done successfully!")

registration()
```

This hides the password entry with `*` by default:

```
Enter first name: John 
Enter last name: Doe
Enter your gender: m
Enter your age: 32
Enter your phone number: 12345
Enter your city: london
Enter your email id: abcde
Enter your password: *********
Re-enter your password: ******
```

Comment: As mentioned in question body I have successfully installed " pwinput " module but during import Python is showing "pwinput" is not accessed Pylance.

Comment: This hints at a problem with your environment. Do you have an ImportError when you try to run the code? Do you use vscode? Check your python version in the console and in vscode. Also run `python -m pip install pwinput` instead.

Comment: Yes I use VS Code. I didn't face any ImportError instead it is showing 

Anshus-MacBook-Air:Test file ansusinha$ /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/ansusinha/Desktop/Test file/sql.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ansusinha/Desktop/Test file/sql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pwinput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwinput'

And when I run this :
pip install pwinput it gives requirement already satisfied

Comment: The problem is resloved now. But simultaneously new problem got raised that pwinput module is not callable

Comment: See the first line of my code. Thé function you're trying to use is called pwinput inside the pwinput module. You either import the module (`import pwinput`) and call the function with `pwinput.pwinput(...)`. Or `from pwinput import pwinput` and call the function directly: `pwinput(...)`

Comment: All problem resolved..!!